# Network connectivity issue between different hosts from a network namespace in one host

Tags: linux, networking, ip, virtualization, namespace

I have created two Ubuntu 12.04 VMs  using VMWare Player with NAT network configuration. I am able to ping them from each other. After that, I created a network namespace in one of them and add a virtual interface. From the network namespace I can access the physical interface of the VM via the other end of the virtual interface which resides in the default namespace by adding a route in the namespace. I have enabled `ip_forward` for the VM which causes access to the Internet from the network namespace. However, I could not ping the other VM in the private network from the namespace. Can anyone explain the reason behind this. I am attaching my configuration:

1. Create a network namespace and make communication between virtual interfaces:

   ```
   sudo ip netns add vnet  
   ip netns list
   sudo ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
   ip link
   sudo ip link set veth1 netns vnet
   sudo ip netns exec vnet ip link list
   sudo ip netns exec vnet ip link set dev lo up
   ip netns exec vnet ping -c5 127.0.0.1
   sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev veth0
   sudo ip link set dev veth0 up
   ip netns exec vnet ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev veth1
   ip netns exec vnet ip link set dev veth1 up
   ip netns exec vnet ping -c5 10.0.0.1
   ```
2. Communication of virtual interfaces with the physical interfaces:

   ```
   sudo ip netns exec vnet route add default gw 10.0.0.1 veth1
   ```
3. Communication of virtual interfaces with outside world:

   ```
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/veth0/proxy_arp
   ```